# disable two controls using one radio box in JSF Primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have to disable two controls on the page using one pair of radio buttons
I have the following code:

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="console" binding="#{yesOrNo}" required="true">}">
  <f:selectItem itemValue="Yes" itemLabel="UPLOAD CLR" />
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="No" itemLabel="ORDER NUMBER" />
<p:ajax update="yesdata" />
        </p:selectOneRadio>     
         <p:fileUpload  id="yesdata"  fileUploadListener="#cBean.handleFileUpload}"
                label="Upload NC CLR" mode="advanced" multiple="false"
                update="createConfigPanel" auto="true" sizeLimit="100000" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xls|xlsx)$/"  disabled="#yesOrNo.value != 'Yes'}" />
```

The problem with the above code is I cannot use the same ID for another control. Code continued:

```
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="8">
        <p:outputLabel for="serviceType" value="Service Type" />
                    <p:inputText id="serviceType"
                        value="#{cBean.serviceType}" required="true"></p:inputText>
...
```

I want to disable this input box when UPLOAD CLR is clicked in the above case.

Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define multiple components to update in `update` attribute. Just add another id like:

```
update="id1 id2"
```

Comment: Wow! thanks so much . It works. On the same note could you tell me how can you learn these little details as the primefaces site has very straightforward stuff

Comment: Also, If I need to update a bean variable at the same time  on the radio button click how will I do it?

Comment: You mean inside the bean? For that purpose you can add listener to ajax and invoke method inside your bean.

Comment: @Sahana: This is all basic JSF, nothing PrimeFaces related. Take a look at http://jsf.zeef.com for generic information

Comment: @Szarpul I have seen something like this explained in another thread:`code`<h:selectOneRadio value="#{myBean.yesNo}" valueChangeListener="#{mybean.checkSelectedVal}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="yes" itemLabel="YES" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="no" itemLabel="NO" />
    <f:ajax event="click" execute="@this" render="mycal">
</h:selectOneRadio>

<p:calendar id="mycal" value="#{myBean.date}" disbaled="#{myBean.caldisabled}"/>  This does not work but. Again I need to disable two controls based on the value